# rails form_tag leaving sticky params in pagination url generated by the kaminari gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

I have a form_tag declaration:

```
<%= form_tag(:action => :index) do %>
```

It was working fine until I upgraded to Rails 4. Now all the params from this form continue to stay in the address bar, and forcing their value on all future invocations of this form.

I have managed to workaround for now by adding the following code to the controller after consuming these params:

```
arr = %i(prev_bal as_of amtpaid pmt_date apr authenticity_token commit int_day new_curbal utf8)
arr.each { |sym| params[sym] = nil }
```

I would appreciate a cleaner way to resolve this.

Thanks for taking the time to help.

*UPDATE*

The pagination links created by kaminari are the only ones with the params in the url. The only param those links should have is `?page=`.

Comment: Add view and controller, please.

Comment: Suspect related to turbolinks.

Comment: @sevenseacat That was a good suspect. But the problem persists even after I removed turbolinks from Gemfile. That does however makes me think of kaminari. Now I notice that it is only happening on the page links, and I had to move from will_paginate to kaminari.